# Flutter Firebase Group Inapp Message Notification

Tags: flutter

I have the below function for private chat notifications in Flutter. I'd like to do the same for a group chat where there are multiple recipentids. How can I achieve that by having multiple recipientids in an array so all the users (except the sender) get notified?

```
gmNotification(String recipientid) {
    String notificationid = const Uuid().v1();
    String res = "Some error occurred";
    try {{
          FirebaseFirestore.instance
              .collection('notifications')
              .doc(recipientid)
              .collection('private-message-notifications')
              .doc(notificationid)
              .set({
              'notificationid': notificationid,
              'timestamp': DateTime.now(),
              },
          );
      }
      res = 'success';
    } catch (err) {
      res = err.toString();
    }
    return res;
  }
```